# More than 3 seconds "Initial Connection" time (webpagetest.org)

Tags: linux, web-server, litespeed

I'm having a weird issue with a vBulletin forum, on a 2х Xeon E5645 w/ 16GB RAM CentOS 6.3 x86_64 web server with cPanel and LiteSpeed; It takes too long to start loading...

When I tested it with webpagetest.org I saw that for every request there's a 3 second "Initial connection" delay, which I don't know why is happening. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

CPU Load is between 0.03 and 0.05, I've got several GB of free RAM, practical no I/O activity, and this delay can occur even with only one visitor on the forum.

Where do you suggest I start searching? What could be the reason for this kind of delay? I don't think it's the webserver, or the forum because there's another website on the server (total 2 sites) which is WordPress based, and has exactly the same issue with the 3 second initial connection delay. I believe it's OS related, but need a clue on where to start looking.

Comment: Latency/network congestion? Where are you running the test from/to (geographically)

Comment: I don't think so, since pinging the server is at around 60ms. Same delay is shown at tools.pingdom.com too, whether I run the test from Amsterdam or Dallas. It must be something OS related I guess.

Comment: What Linux distro and version are you running?

Comment: @Starfish CentOS 6.3 x86_64

Comment: Did the dns lookup solve the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check reverse DNS -- the logging on the web server may be trying to lookup the name of the client, and timing out.

Test it by putting a known IP address in the /etc/hosts table, make sure you can ping by name (lookup working -- if not check the /etc/resolv.conf).

Answer (score 1):

This makes me think about MTU issues. Ping will work fine because it sends shorts packets, but what happens when you ping with larger packets ? And you did disable jumbo frames, did you ?

```
ping -s 1500 your_server
```

Either that, or a firewall in the middle does not like your initial TCP parameters or MTU, and/or block 'fragmentation needed' ICMP errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: [OpenDNS - Cloud Internet Security and DNS](http://www.opendns.com/).

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
$
```